# Relationship API name for UserPackageLicenses on PackageLicense?

Tags: soql, licenses, userlicense

I'm trying to select my user licenses in the same query with all the licenses, but I didn't find a way to figure out the relationship api name between them:

This is not valid:

```
SELECT NamespacePrefix, (SELECT Id FROM UserPackageLicenses)
FROM PackageLicense
```

> Didn't understand relationship 'UserPackageLicenses'

The other way it works like this:

```
SELECT PackageLicense.NamespacePrefix FROM UserPackageLicense
```

So why does it not work the other way arround, or how to I figure out the api name?

Comment: This issue looks similar - [Unable to query user fields from UserPackageLicense](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000sXtWAAU), It also states `This is because there is no Relationship defined for User in the UserPackageLicense API.`, What are you trying to do?

Comment: You are right, it's similar, but not the same. I'm not accessing the user, but PackageLicense it's UserPackageLicense and I'm doing it the other way, with a relationship query. I'm trying to find all possible licences and want to know if the user has it, both at the same time.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't seem to be possible, tried to access relationship name by describe call, returns null.  Need to separate queries for this.

Answer (score 2):

When you check salesforce data model via Force.com IDE you will see that it is a special kind of relationship configured by Salesforce and there is no Relationship name (used in queries).

Check the screenshot:

[image]